# How to import all the classes in a module as a list?

Tags: python, django

In django, to display models on admin page, we have to first register all the models in admin.py.
If there are so many models to register, we have to write admin.site.register(model_name) so many times.
Its kind of a boring task.
So I was wondering if there is any way in python to import all the classes in module as list.
for instance, admin.py,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import * as list_name           #like this is there any way we can get all things inside * in list ?

for i in list_name:
    admin.site.register(i)          #so that this way I have to write only one line of code to  register all classes.
```

Is there any way to save writing lot of lines here ?

Comment: Look into `dir` (e.g. `for i in dir(models): if {i is model}: register(i)`)

Comment: its not working. or maybe I am not doing correctly. Can you give an example or send some link?

Comment: Put your models in a container, like a list, to begin with. In general, btw, using starred imports is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function will be useful here. Something like:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Model

import models

for i in dir(models):
    m = getattr(models, i)
    if isinstance(m, Model):
        admin.site.register(m)
```

Comment: use `for name, attribute in vars(models).items()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `site.register` allow you to pass a model or iterable of models ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.register)) - so you can simply pass a list of models you want to register. To accomplish this automatically - without ever needing to edit the `admin.py` module - I suggest to reimport your models in an `__init__.py` file.

```
from my_app import models

site.register(map(models.__dict__.get, models.__all__))
```

Content of `my_app.models.__init__.py`:

```
from .cat import Cat
from .dog import Dog

__all__ = ["Cat", "Dog"]
```